# Can't get Doctrine DBAL to bind value as an int

Tags: doctrine, silex

I have a silex app that uses the DoctrineServiceProvider where I have a query like:

```
$app['db']->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar= ? LIMIT ?', array('baz',$limit));
```

Where limit is coming in from a query string - `$limit = $request->get('limit')`. It's throwing a `PDOException` as it seems to be treating $limit as a string and trying to do `LIMIT '10'` and not `LIMIT 10`

I have tried adding `array(\PDO::PARAM_STR,\PDO::PARAM_INT)` to the call to `fetchAll` but doesn't seem to help.

I've also tried doing it the long way with $app['db']->prepare, $app['db']->bindValue etc but that didn't fly either.

Is this something I should be able to do? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: IIRC limit is one of the few places where you cannot use parameters.

Comment: That seems like a shame. If that's true I guess it's nice to know it's not me for a change. What would be the best alternative do you think?

Comment: I validate the limit manually, then use `sprintf` and `%d` to create the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LIMIT` is one of the few places where MySQL cannot handle prepared statement parameters<sup>[citation needed]</sup>.

Depending on where you get it from either

- make sure you validate user input correctly
- make sure you're generating an integer

and then use string concatenation to create the query, or a bit more elegant way, with `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT %d", $limit);
```